# ClickOnce with non renferenced dll

Tags: c#, dll, clickonce

Im trying to create a ClickOnce application that needs some dlls, that can't be referenced, added on it's instalation folder for it to work.

I'm currently using a post-build event to get those dlls when in debug mode:

```
xcopy /y /d  "$(ProjectDir)..\libraries\$(PlatformName)\*.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```

But obviously on the installer it doesn't take those dlls into account, which means that when I try to run the program it fails to run the methods that come from those dlls, since it needs those dlls.

Is there a way to send those dlls in the ClickOnce Instalation?

I've been searching for a way to do this, but haven't found any clear solution, if this question is a duplicate, please reference the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to make this work by literally just adding the dlls to the project, I didn't reference them, just added them and they now go with the installer.